# Is possible to extend from Twig_Lexer?

Tags: twig

In Twig [internal documentation](https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/internals.html) we can read that lexer could be changed:

```
$twig->setLexer($lexer);
```

My question is: Is possible to extend from `Twig_Lexer`?

When reading the code I can see most members are `private`, this makes harder the reuse of members or extending at all. Also the `setLexer()` from `Twig_Environment` has a type hint for `Twig_Lexer`.

What am I missing here ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As documentation purpose. The answer to this question can be seen in [this issue](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/issues/2451)

Basically all extension from internal classes is discouraged and will not be supported in Twig.